# Android Layout XML file with class

Tags: java, android, xml, class, android-activity

I created a class that extends RelativeLayout.
I also created a xml layout file.

How can I 'connect' between them as I connect Activities with their xml files
(`setContentView(R.layout.main);`)

Thanks!

Comment: show your created xml and extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you can use LayoutInflater to load the xml in the relative layout, but am not sure that what you should be doing. I am not sure what your trying to do but your wrapping your layout inside another view by doing this. When you can just load the xml straight into your view using the same tactic. So you lose one level of complexity.

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view,null);
  addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the layout using the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) right in your constructor.

```
public class RelSub extends RelativeLayout {
        public RelSub(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, this);

        }

    }
```